# Nested namespace didn`t see a class which is nested in another namespace by using 'using-directive'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, namespaces

Namespace 'w' didn`t see class 'z' which is nested in namespace x::y::z by using "using namespace x::y::z;" declaraion. I am using visual studio 2010. What is wrong?

```
//...
namespace x
{
    namespace y
    {
        namespace z
        {
            class z
            {
            public:
                z(){};
            };
        }
    }
}
using namespace x::y::z; // normal declaration
namespace x
{
 namespace y
 {
  namespace w
  {
   class w
   {
    z object; // Here is the problem. Type 'z' is underlined in visual studio!
              // When I did like this:
              // x::y::z::z object;
              // everything is compiling properly
   };
  }
 }
}
int main()
{
    z object;       // no problem - I declared namespace above
    x::y::z::z object2; // also no problem
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happened because of name collision between  `z` namespace, and `z` class. Change the class name to `c` for instance, and everything will work fine as [here](http://codepad.org/rpGiVJCQ).

BTW, try as much as possible to avoid *using-directive*, as it gives lots of headache sometimes.

Comment: Okay, well done. But in my opinion everything should be ok in my code.
I have used "using declaration". When I try to create an object 'z'
compilator should know what is this type. I wrote clearly 'z'. 
I know that this is the same name as namespace but I think that
using this is correct. Creating an object in that place is not 
connected with expanding a namespace 'z'.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it because you've got `class w` in the `x::y::w` namespace and class z in the `x::y::z` namespace?

Even though you say `using namespace x::y::z`, when you start declaring new spaces I don't think that's taken into consideration - meaning namespace `w` can't see into `z`

What you can do, however, is utilise the fact that `x::y` is shared in both `w` and `z`. You can't see the `z` CLASS, but you CAN see the `z` NAMESPACE, because it's in `y` (which `w` is also in). So you can go:

```
class w {
    z::z object;
}
```

The little example I tested with is:

```
#include <iostream>
namespace x {
    namespace y {
        namespace z {
            class z {
            public:
                z() { cout << "x::y::z::z" << endl; }
            }
        }
    }
}
namespace x {
    namespace y {
        namespace w {
            class w {
                z::z object;
            public:
                w() { cout << "x::y::w::w" << endl; }
            }
        }
    }
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    x::y::w::w object;
    return 0;
}
```

And the output of this is:

```
x::y::z::z
x::y::w::w
```

Comment: So namespace don`t take into consideration another namespace? So we still have to specify the range?

Comment: Not verified, but I believe when you DEFINE namespaces, it doesn't take into consideration what you're already `using`. If anyone could verify that, that'd be sweet :D